# Android: Push features into application

Tags: android, plugins, apk

I am developing an Android application where I want people to buy a licence, and based on that licence I will need to push plugins to my application.

e.g. if the licence maps to 3 plugins (or premium features), I want to push only those 3 to the application at run time. Since it's not possible to change the APK like this AFAIK, and I don't want to include all the features in a single APK.

How can I maintain multiple versions of the app, like a premium app and free app without maintaining multiple apks?

Best Regards

Comment: Is Android InApp Billing not feasible for you?

Comment: No, I don't want payments through the app. We have a web portal where a company purchases the plugins and we distribute them to all the employees. In App billing will just help me simplify the billing process, right? And not help me write a plugin based architecture. I may be missing something huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins are nothing but APKs without a launcher activity AFAIK. Just take the example of the Facebook. How does the application know whether you have their **Pages Manager** or **Messenger** installed ? I can only think of one way of achieving this so-called Plugin Based Architecture i.e. Create multiple APKs, one for each plugin, acting as a stand-alone application. And check if the package exists at Runtime with the Main APK.

```
public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
        pm = getPackageManager();        
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage)) return true;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

If not downloaded and install the package if it meets your criteria.

```
How do I make sure that only my "master" apk is able to call the functions in the plugin apk?
```

You can do that by adding this to your Manifest file
`android:protectionLevel="signature"`.

You can read about it more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html).

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: How do I make sure that only my "master" apk is able to call the functions in the plugin apk?